# CQL: Escape single quote in a map<int,text> attribute

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-3.0, cqlsh, cql3

For `text` attributes, CQL allows escaping single quote [using additional single quote](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cassandra-user/201108.mbox/%3C20110803152250.294300@gmx.net%3E). But applying the same syntax for a `map<int,text>` attribute does not work.

CREATE query:
`CREATE TABLE university.test (id int, data map<int, text>, PRIMARY KEY (id));`

INSERT query:
`insert into university.test (id, data) values(1, {1:'I''m newb'});`

On running the aforementioned INSERT query, Cassandra inserts and returns `{1: 'I''m newb'}` while the expected result is `{1: 'I'm newb'}`

Screenshot FR:

[image: Screenshot]

**How to escape single quote `'` while inserting in a `map<int,text>` attribute?**

Comment: I think that's a bug.  Cassandra *should* totally treat those strings the same way, regardless of whether or not it's a `text` or a `map`.

Comment: @Aaron Thanks for your reply. I have [reported a bug on Cassandra's JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-15458), please review/add as required.